# IHttpActionResult variable passing null in test method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, asp.net-web-api2, actionmethod

I am writing a test method for an IHttpActionresult controller. The ActionResult is not NULL and contains the required data (Customer.ID = 986574123). However in line two the variable CreatedResult is null. I want it to return the appropriate data to CreatedResult. I am also using Moq framework. Don't know if that matters. Any thoughts? If you need more data from ActionResult please comment below. Thx.

Test Method Code:

```
        var CustomerRepository = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();

        CustomerRepository.Setup(x => x.Add()).Returns(new Customer { ID = 986574123, Date = DateTime.Now});      

        var Controller = new CustomerController(CustomerRepository.Object, new Mock<IProductRepository>().Object);
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:38306/api/CreateCustomer");
        var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}");
        var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Customers" } });
        Controller.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request);
        Controller.Request = request;
        Controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;

        IHttpActionResult ActionResult = Controller.CreateCustomer();
        // Null occurs here
        var CreatedResult = ActionResult as CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult<Customer>;
```

CreateCustomer Add method:

```
         [Route("api/createcustomer")]
         [HttpPost]
         public IHttpActionResult CreateCustomer()
         {
             Customer NewCustomer = CustomerRepository.Add();

             return Created(Request.RequestUri + "/" + NewCustomer.ID.ToString(), new { customerID = NewCustomer.ID });
         }
```

ActionResult Data:

```
-       Location    {http://localhost:38306/api/createcustomer/986574123}   System.Uri
        AbsolutePath    "/api/createcustomer/986574123" string
        AbsoluteUri "http://localhost:38306/api/createcustomer/986574123"   string
        Authority   "localhost:38306"   string
        DnsSafeHost "localhost" string
        Fragment    ""  string
        Host    "localhost" string
        HostNameType    Dns System.UriHostNameType
        IsAbsoluteUri   true    bool
        IsDefaultPort   false   bool
        IsFile  false   bool
        IsLoopback  true    bool
        IsUnc   false   bool
        LocalPath   "/api/createCustomer/986574123" string
        OriginalString  "http://localhost:38306/api/createcustomer/986574123"   string
        PathAndQuery    "/api/createCustomer/986574123" string
        Port    38306   int
        Query   ""  string
        Scheme  "http"  string
+       Segments    {string[4]} string[]
        UserEscaped false   bool
        UserInfo    ""  string
```

Comment: Since we know the type of `CreatedResult` is not `CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult<Customer>`, what *is* its type?

Comment: The type is anonymous

Comment: Well, *that's* the problem then. [Anonymous types cannot be type-casted into any other type (besides `Object`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

Comment: How would I fix the code while make sure the JSON returned would be the same as following { customerID = NewCustomer.ID }?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest change to make your test to pass would be change this line

```
return Created(Request.RequestUri + "/" + NewCustomer.ID.ToString(), new { customerID = NewCustomer.ID });
```

to the following

```
return Created(Request.RequestUri + "/" + NewCustomer.ID.ToString(), NewCustomer);
```

The problem is that that the type parameter of your CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult is not what you expect. You try to cast the `result` to a `CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult<Customer>` when in fact its type is `CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult<AnonymousType#1>`, so the cast fails and returns `null`.

The reason for this is that ApiController's [`Create(String, T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337088%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method returns a CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult whose type parameter `T` is the type of the `content` you pass in, and you're passing in an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

---

You want to use the anonymous type return only certain fields from your model, but you also want to refer to this type outside of the context where it is declared (i.e. in your unit test). This isn't possible, see the above link about anonymous types (`If you must store query results or pass them outside the method boundary, consider using an ordinary named struct or class instead of an anonymous type.`)

So, if you want to return just certain fields, you'll need to create a specific view model for this purpose.

```
class CustomerDetails
{
     public int customerID { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your action method

```
return Created(Request.RequestUri + "/" + NewCustomer.ID.ToString(), new CustomerDetails { customerID = NewCustomer.ID });
```

Comment: Okay I added more information. What conditions are required to be meet?

Comment: @user3754602 I updated my answer in the light of the new information you provided.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to return something like this "new { customerID = NewCustomer.ID }"? I don't want to send back to the client all the Customer Data and I want the JSON variable to be named customerID

Comment: Is there a way to cast an AnonymousType to Customer? Then pass it through CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult?

Comment: @user3754602 you can't cast anonymous types to anything other than Object (the MSDN documentation states this). See my answer for another possible solution.

Comment: Okay thx. Is there a point to create a CustomerDetails against an interface?

Comment: No worries. If it's just a record with no methods, I wouldn't bother creating an interface for it. What's the point? See here for more discussion: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159813